# Approximation from discrete Kronecker Delta to continuum Dirac Delta

Tags: hilbert-space, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, second-quantization, discrete

I am working on second quantization of the Dirac field with discrete momentum I was asked to compute the creation/annihilation anticommutator by imposing the anticommutators on $\psi$ i.e.

$$ \{\psi_a(\vec{x}),\psi^{\dagger}_b(\vec{y})\} = \delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}-\vec{y})\delta_{ab}$$

I start with:

$$\psi(\vec{x}) = \sum_{r,\vec{k}} \sqrt{\dfrac{m}{VE_{\vec{k}}}}\bigg[  c_k(\vec{k})\,u_r(\vec{k}) \,e^{-i x \cdot p} + d^{\dagger}_r(\vec{k})\,v_r(\vec{k})\, e^{ix \cdot p} \bigg] $$

Since I am trying to isolate $c$ and $d$ I try to multiply for the expoencial $e^{ix\cdot p'}$ and integrate over the volume, and I will apear an integral like this

$$\iiint_V e^{-i \,x \cdot (p'-p)} \,d^3x$$

Is there any way approximate this? Like doing:

$$\iiint_V e^{-i \,x \cdot (p'-p)} \,d^3x \approx V\delta_{p,\,p'}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: none]

Cited from Mahan's book. It may help you.

Comment: Hi Fabregas, welcome to Physics SE! As a general rule, both questions and answers should avoid using images of text.  Instead, please type whatever answers you'd like to provide, and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset any mathematical expressions.  That way your answers will render properly in all browsers, and will be able to be indexed by search engines.

Comment: Thank you! It really helped. I noticed that the creation/annihilation operators do not depend on the volume. So I can take V to infinity. Make the delta appear, and convert it back to the discret delta function and make the summation disapear!

Comment: @J.Murray Thank you for your reminder. I won't do that next time :-)

Comment: @JoãoViana You're welcome.